# How to merge two Dataset/Table using Joins or any other operations in Python or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, join, merge

I have two tables/Datasets. 1st table consists of 3 rows and the 2nd table consists of 97 rows. 
I need to merge both these datasets/tables, so i get a final output of 100 rows in a table/dataset.
I tried using, Inner Join, Full outer Join. But none are giving me the required result.

Please let me know, what **Joins** or **Operations** I can use using either **SQL** or **Python Script**.

```
Timestamp             kW_System   Anomaly score  Alert indicator
2016-09-08T07:17:07Z  174.877105  1.455553       1
2016-09-13T09:32:07Z  175.462994  0.952738       1
2017-01-14T23:03:07Z  181.580188  1.057076       1


Timestamp             kW_System Anomaly score  Alert indicator
2016-09-14T21:33:07Z  0         1.056694         1
2016-09-14T22:03:07Z  0         1.226853         1
2016-09-14T22:33:07Z  0         1.265696         1
.
.
.
.
.
.
2016-12-17T05:48:07Z   2.10767   2.599405        1
2016-12-17T06:18:07Z   2.306138  1.370845        1
2016-12-17T07:18:07Z   2.089892  1.887742        1
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it right. So you want to create a new table containing records from both tables put together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UNION operator (or UNION ALL if you don't want to remove duplicate row)

```
SELECT * FROM 1st table
UNION
SELECT * FROM 2nd table
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want them gathered into a new table, create the new table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl1;
```

Then insert the data from your two tables:

```
INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl1;
INSERT INTO new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl2;
```

If you want to collect all the rows in one of your existing tables, just adapt the insert statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO orig_tbl1 SELECT * FROM orig_tbl2;
```

This should work in MySQL. There will be very similar statements in most other database systems.

Answer (score 0):

We can emulate it by doing a UNION of a left join and a right join, like this:

```
-- t1 left join t2
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
UNION ALL -- include duplicates
-- t1 right exclude join t2 (records found only in t2)
SELECT * FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2;
```